# Given $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a+b+c=a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and $0<a<1$ show that $bc<0$

Tags: inequality

These seems like it should be really simple but I can't seem to crack it. I've tried taking $(a+b-c)^2 >  0$ but am getting nowhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

$$2bc = (b + c)^2 - b^2 - c^2 = (1 - a)^2 - (1 - a^2) = -2a + 2a^2 = -2a(1 - a) < 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Given
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}b+c&=& 1-a\\ b^2+c^2&=&1-a^2\end{array}\right.$$
we may find $b$ and $c$ as the roots of a quadratic polynomial. In particular
$$ 2bc = (b+c)^2-(b^2+c^2) = (1-a)^2-(1-a^2) = -2a+2a^2 = -2a(1-a)<0 $$
so, if existing, $b$ and $c$ have opposite signs. $b$ and $c$ are roots of 
$$ p(z) = z^2-(1-a)z-2a(1-a) $$
whose discriminant is 
$$ \Delta(p) = (1-a)^2 + 4a(1-a) > 0 $$
so $b$ and $c$ actually are real numbers with opposite signs.

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from user780985, but a geometric approach is helpful too.

The shapes are the plane $a+b+c=1$ and the sphere $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$; the condition is that their intersection has no solution in the positive octant $0<a,b,c$. A look at a graph might convince you:

[image]

We can parametrize their intersection by
$$\gamma(t)=\frac{1}{3}
\bigg\{ 2 \cos (t)+1, -\sqrt{3} \sin (t)-\cos
   (t)+1, \sqrt{3} \sin (t)-\cos (t)+1\bigg\},\,0\leq t\leq 2\pi
$$Then either by algebra or by graphing, we see that the three components are never mutually positive.

[image]